# Grails add a controller action in runtime

Tags: grails, groovy

I need to add a controller action on runtime. 
In a plugin i add a dynamic method using doWithDynamicMethods but i can't invoke as an action.

I try using a mixin but it doesnt work. There is a bug with @grails.web.Mixin and is useless for me. And i'm not sure if i can call it as an action.

I understood that i need to add the @Action annotation to method that i create dynamiclly in the doWithDynamicMethods.

Should i use an AstTransformation. Or i  miss something

Comment: Slow down here chief, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to add a controller action on runtime.

No, you don't.  You've got some other problem, and you think you can solve it by adding a controller action during runtime.  But as you've learned, adding controller actions during runtime is really hard.  *You should solve your problem in some other way*.

I don't know what your problem is, so I can't be too specific.  But here's a generically useful trick.  In `UrlMappings.groovy`, you can do this:

```
"awesome/$stuff"(controller: 'awesome', action: 'doStuff')
```

And then in AwesomeController.groovy:

```
public doStuff(String stuff) {
  // whatever arbitrary dynamic dispatch logic you want goes here
}
```

Hope that helps.